# Input должен обводиться границей если не удовлетворяет атрибуты валидации

Tags: html, scss

У меня есть разметка формы. Там есть инпут с userName. Как с помощью css стилей (при этом ничего не меняя в самой разметке) чтобы при загрузке страницы этот инпут был уже обведен красной границей пока пользователь не ввел что-нибудь?

Пробовал

```
#userName:valid {
    border: 3px solid red;
  }
```

Но тогда если пользователь что-то введет, то граница останется. А нужно чтобы пропадала.

```
<main class="page">
      <form class="login-form">
        <div class="form-control">
          <label class="form-label" for="userName">Full Name</label>
          <input class="form-input" type="text" id="userName" name="userName" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
          <label class="form-label" for="password">Password</label>
          <input class="form-input" type="password" id="password" name="password" required />
        </div>
        <button class="submit-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Требуется сочетание псевдокласса `:invalid` и атрибута `required`:

```css
#userName:invalid {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input class="form-input" type="text" id="userName" name="userName" required />
```

Comment: html должен оставаться неизменным

Comment: Т.е. только CSS и без JS?

Comment: да, только с помощью стилей

Comment: Тогда набирайтесь [терпения](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:blank)